# SED Code Explanation

Tags: sed

I have a line of SED, below, that is in a batch command that I run every month. It was written by someone before me, and I am looking to understand the parts of this code. From the two outputs I can tell that it takes one line and deletes another when sequential lines are duplicates, I just don't understand how it is being done with this line.

```
sed "$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D" finalish.txt > final.txt
```

Exmple of - Finalish.txt

```
201408
201409
201409
201409
201409
```

Example of - Final.txt

```
201408
201409
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what it looks like? I'm asking, because the shell will substitute variables within double quotes, and `$!` expands to the PID of the most recently executed background process, which is likely to result in `sed` seeing some unexpected input... (The `$/` will not be expanded, since it's not a valid variable).

Comment: @twalberg Yeah I just double checked and that is exactly how it appears in the code and it works. My computer is weird though and for any sed command it wont work with single quotes (like most places say it should) but will work with no quotes - most of the time. For this line it only works if I use double quotes.

Comment: @user2755209 Running you command on my `ubuntu` and I get this error `-bash: !P: event not found`. What OS are you on.

Comment: @user2755209 Windows 7. It works on my computer so I'm not worried about that just trying to figure out what the different parts of that line are doing/saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going in to the basics of `sed`, here is your `sed` command broken down:

- `$!N`: If it is not end of file, append next line to pattern space. The two lines will be separated by a newline (`\n`). At this time your pattern space is `201408\n201409`.
- `/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P`: If the pattern space **does not** contain two similar content separated by a newline (`\n`), then `P`rint up to the first newline (`\n`). So this will print `201408` to STDOUT. During the second iteration though, the pattern space will have  `201409\n201409` and since it **fails** the regex, nothing gets printed and we proceed to the next command.
- `D`: `D`eletes up to the first newline (`\n`) and repeats the `sed` script. Remember during the repeat cycle your pattern space still has the `201409`

So during the first iteration `201408` gets printed but `201409` doesn't get printed until the end of file is reached which is when your regex will become true again and the content will get printed.

If you are inheriting alot of `sed` code, I would strongly recommend [sedsed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/) utility which is written in `python` and will help you understand convoluted and cryptic `sed` that can often become a maintenance nightmare.

Here is a sample run from the `sedsed` utility (I haven't shown all iterations as it is pretty verbose but you get the picture. I have added few comments to what the output really means. Also notice I am using single quotes since I am on Mac (BSD Unix) and not Windows):

```
$ sedsed.py -d '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' file
PATT:201408$           # This shows your current pattern space
HOLD:$                 # This shows your current hold buffer
COMM:$ !N              # This shows the command that is going to run
PATT:201408$           # This shows the pattern space after the command has ran
201409$           
HOLD:$                 # This shows the hold buffer after the command has ran
COMM:/^\(.*\)\n\1$/ !P # This shows the command being ran
201408                 # Anything without a <TAG:> is what gets printed to STDOUT
PATT:201408$
201409$
HOLD:$
COMM:D
PATT:201409$
HOLD:$
...
...
...
COMM:$ !N
PATT:201409$
HOLD:$
COMM:/^\(.*\)\n\1$/ !P
201409
PATT:201409$
HOLD:$
COMM:D
```

I would also suggest that once you get the idea of what your `sed` commands were written for, you port them to a more friendlier scripting language like `awk`, `perl` or `python`

Answer (score 0):

This will not help you understanding the `sed`, but here is an `awk` that just get the unique lines.

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' finalish.txt
201408
201409
```

Comment: That will pick out equivalent lines that are non-adjacent, though, which does not seem to be the intended effect...

Comment: @twalberg Then some like this would do: `awk 'NR>1 && $0!=a {print a} {a=$0} END {print}' file`